# Typescript, Jest and i18next: Can't see text in React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme, i18next

I am testing a React component that uses [i18next](http://i18next.com/) for internationalization.

The component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { t } from "i18next";

export function Hello(_props) {
  return <div className="widget-header">
    {t("Hello, world!")}
  </div>;
}
```

The test:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "enzyme";
import { Hello } from "./hello";

describe("<Hello />", () => {
  it("says hi", () => {
    let hi = render(<Hello />);
    // FAILS!
    // Expected "" to contain "Hello"
    expect(hi.text()).toContain("Hello");
  });
})
```

My suspicion is that Jest is stubbing `i18next.t()` to return `undefined` rather than "Hello, world!", but I am unsure of that.

I have tried to `unmock("i18next")` without any luck.

**How do I write tests for i18next components in Jest?**

**UPDATE:** I was using Typescript as my compiler. It appears that there is a [hoisting issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1273) with the loader I use for Typescript (ES6 hoists imports, `jest.unmock` is not- Babel users have a plugin to handle this).

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(t("Hello, world!"))` your file, just to check if the problem is really related to `i18next`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why its not working but you can just mock put `i18next` like this:

```
jest.mock('i18next', () => ({
  t: (i) => i
}))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. It looks like my issue was with Typescript compiler. I have updated the description.